# How to configure prettier such that it formats jsx attributes in multiple lines in VSCODE?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx, prettier

I would like this:

```
    <input
       id="inputForEmail"
       type="email"
       className="form-control"
       aria-describedby="Enter email address"
       placeholder="Enter email address"
    />
```

As opposed to this:

```
<input id="inputForEmail" type="email" className="form-control" aria-describedby="Enter email address" placeholder="Enter email address" />
```

Comment: What is the code editor you're using?

Comment: oh vscode, i will edit that in

Comment: I'm looking for the same, elint shows its a prettier error but don't say its rule name so I could disable it.

Answer (score 1):

If you use the `.prettierrc.js` file for prettier configuration, try adding the [singleAttributePerLine](https://prettier.io/docs/en/options.html#single-attribute-per-line) option like this:

```js
module.exports = {
    singleAttributePerLine: true,
};
```

Answer (score -1):

VSCode added a way to do this now. You can edit your settings.json (ctrl+shift+p) and then add the following for the desired effect:

```
"html.format.wrapAttributes": "force-aligned"
```

--or--

```
"html.format.wrapAttributes": "force"
```

force-aligned will also add indents to align it with the attribute on the line where tag was opened.

**OR**

You can go to extensions in the editor and search for prettier then install it. Then you don't need to setting up anything just go to your code and press shift + i or shift+alt+f . Cheers! your code is nicely formatted.

https://prettier.io/

Comment: Most of this has nothing to do with the question.

Answer (score -2):

1. Go to extension (Ctrl+Shift+X), click on Prettier
2. Click on settings icon and select extension settings
3. Type print width and change the value